# How to set div background color to 'none' using jQuery's css?

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('#element').css({'background-color':'none'});
```

The code above doesn't work. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 53):

you can use one of these two options (i recommend the **second** one):

**option 1:**

```
$('#element').css('background-color','transparent');
```

**option 2:**

```
$('#element').css('background-color','inherit');
```

Comment: What is the difference between option 1 and 2

Comment: inherit: if its parent is red then the element would be red too, if the parent is transparent, the element would be transparent too. and in 'transparent' mode, the element does not have any background-color and shows whatever the parent shows.

Comment: Why do you recommend the second one? If the parent element has a semi-transparent background (e.g. `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`), this will yield unexpected results. Setting the background-color to transparent is closer to the default non-existing background.

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

```
$('#element').css({'background-color':'transparent'});
```

You can also try

```
$('#element').css("background-color", "transparent");
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
$('#element').css('background-color','');
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$('#element').css('background-color','transparent');
```

or

```
$('#element').css({ backgroundColor: 'transparent' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `transparent` instead of `none`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#element').css('background-color', '');
```

Comment: this does not seems to work . but setting to '' works

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.divclass')
    .on( "mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "transparent"
        });
    })
    .on( "mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "#000000"
        });
    });
```